# Why i have acess violation when call a function from dll and i use record?

Tags: delphi, dll

I try to call a function to read some bytes from c++ dll. I declared the header of function but when i call and try to assign the array value to a record value, function return access violation in MSVCR80.dll.
Here is my code if i use valueBits record return AV if i use a simple boolean variable it's working. I need an advice please.

```
    function TdmCustom.CheckBon(var valueBits: TStatusPrintingRecord): Boolean;
    var cmd          : String;
    //valueBit     : array[0..10] of AnsiChar;
    MemArea      : PAnsiChar;
    pdwByteRead  : LPDWORD;
    lpdwSysError : LPDWORD;
    aNrComanda   : String;
    Arr          : array of AnsiChar;
begin
  pdwByteRead  := 0;
  lpdwSysError := 0;
  aNrComanda   := '1011';
  cmd        := Format('%S',[aNrComanda]);
  SendCommandToPrinter(cmd,True);
  lastError := CEFReadB(MemArea, &pdwByteRead, &lpdwSysError)//acess violation if i use valueBits record
  SetLength(Arr, Integer(pdwByteRead));
  Move(MemArea^, Arr[0], Integer(pdwByteRead));
  if lastError = 0 then begin
    valueBits.S8_isBonFiscalDeschis   := Arr[8] = '1';
    //valueBits.S9_isBonNefiscalDeschis := Arr[9] = '1';
  end;
  Result := lastError = 0;
end;
```

This is my header of dll function :

```
function CEFReadB(lpMemArea : PAnsiChar; var pdwByteRead : LPDWORD; var lpdwSysError : LPDWORD) : DWORD; cdecl; external DLLName name 'CEFReadCustom' delayed;
```

Comment: Is this what you're trying to do? https://www.board4all.biz/threads/reading-unsigned-char-lpmemarea-from-a-dll.759376/#post-1417740

Comment: Yes it is, but i don't know why i have access violation when i try to use a record and when i am not it's everything ok. I don't know if it's just a coincidence that it works and i need an advice if it's ok.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are various mistakes.

1. First & means something different in Delphi. You probably want @.
2. But you don't need that since you declare the values VAR.
3. But then again you declare them var as pointers (LPdw*). declaring them as VAR eats an indirection, so probably in the declaration the types should be just DWORD.
4. probably also you need to allocate memory to memarea before you pass it to the function
5. and pass the amount allocated in byteread.

I tried to cleanup, and came up with the below code, untested. IF you require more help, please update your post with C++ declaration and usage.

```
function CEFReadB(lpMemArea : PAnsiChar; var byteRead : DWORD; var lpdwSysError : DWORD) : DWORD; cdecl; external DLLName name 'CEFReadCustom' delayed;

function TdmCustom.CheckBon(var valueBits: TStatusPrintingRecord): Boolean;
var cmd          : String;

    MemArea      : ansistring;
    LastError    : DWORD;
    ByteRead     : DWORD;
    SysError     : DWORD;
    aNrComanda   : String;

begin
  byteRead  := 50;
  setlength(memarea,byteread);
  lpdwSysError := 0;
  aNrComanda   := '1011';
  cmd        := Format('%S',[aNrComanda]);
  SendCommandToPrinter(cmd,True);
  lastError := CEFReadB(pansichar(MemArea), byteRead, SysError);
  if lasterror= 0 then  
    begin
      setlength(memarea,byteRead);
      if byteread>=9 then
        begin
         valueBits.S8_isBonFiscalDeschis   := Arr[8] = '1';   // note 8 and 9 are 1-based!
         valueBits.S9_isBonNefiscalDeschis := Arr[9] = '1';
        end
      else 
        exit(False); // not enough data read.
    end; 

  Result := lastError = 0;
end;
```

Comment: `DWORD CEFRead(unsigned char *lpMemArea, LPDWORD pdwByteRead, LPDWORD lpdwSysError)`

Comment: Thank you very much Marco! Now I understand every mistake.

Comment: Note that nothing is done with syserror. Lookup in the documentation what it is good for.

Comment: Ok, but at the end it is necessary to free memory?

Comment: No, ansistring is an automated type.

Comment: Can I copy MemArea directly? Something like this :`if lasterror= 0 then ` 
    `begin`
      `setlength(memarea,byteRead);`
      `if byteread>=9 then`
        `begin`
         `valueBits.S8_isBonFiscalDeschis   := Copy(MemArea,9,1)  = '1'; // like this`
       ` end`
      `else `
        `exit(False); // not enough data read.`
    `end; `